# Sets of polynomials with restricted set of products

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $F = \{f_1, ..., f_n\}$ be a set of distinct monic polynomials (and thus also $f_i^2$ are distinct). Let $F' = \{f_i f_j: i \neq j\}$ be the set of pairwise products of all distinct elements from $F$. We also require that $f_i^2 \neq f_j f_k$ for $j \neq k$.

Question. What is known about the upper and lower bounds on the cardinality of $F'$?

For example, if $F$ is a set of monomials, $f_i (X) = X^{t_i}$, then $F' = X^{t_i + t_j}$. The requirement above translates to the requirement that $(t_1, ..., t_n)$ does not have arithmetic progressions of length $3$. Therefore, one can take $(t_1, ..., t_n)$ to be equal to the progression-free set of Behrend or Elkind to minimize $|F'|$, and use the bound of Sanders to give a lower bound on $|F'|$.

But what happens in the general case?

The problem seems to have some relation to the results of Frankl-Wilson and Grolmusz on restricted intersections, but in our case $f_i^2$ are all distinct, while in their case (this is somewhat imprecise) $f_i^2 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$.

Comment: Polynomials over what ring of coefficients?

Comment: I am specifically interested in the case of polynomials over finite cyclic groups, but any information would be welcome

Comment: If the $f_i$ are irreducible, then the $f_if_j$ for $i<j$ are pairwise different.

Comment: Thanks, nsrt. Yes, this is clearly true - but I have no such restriction on $f_i$. The example above about $f_i (X) = X^{t_i}$ involves reducible polynomials.

Comment: Do you want an upper bound for the minimal cardinality of $F'$ for all possible choices of the $f_i$?

Comment: Also I think there is not much difference between monomials = products of $X_j$ 
and arbitrary polynomials = products of irreducible polynomials.

Comment: I'd like to have any pointers to the corresponding research. The concrete question I am most interested in is to choose $f_i$ so that the cardinality of $F'$ is minimized. It might be the case that the monomial case (or the case $f_i = g (X)^{t_i}$ for some monic irreducible degree $> 0$ polynomial $g$) is already optimal, by a simple argument.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14209/discussion-between-ccat-and-nsrt)